# How to prevent a value from being moved?

Tags: rust, move, lifetime

I'm having a lot of fun trying to solve [the robot simulator Exercism exercise](http://exercism.io/exercises/rust/robot-simulator/readme), but I'm facing a value moving problem for which I don't seem to be able to come up with an elegant solution:

```
impl Robot {
    pub fn new(x: isize, y: isize, d: Direction) -> Self {
        Robot { position: Coordinate { x: x, y: y }, direction: d }
    }

    pub fn turn_right(mut self) -> Self {
        match self.direction {
           // ...
        };
        self
    }

    pub fn turn_left(mut self) -> Self {
        match self.direction {
           // ...
        };
        self
    }

    pub fn advance(mut self) -> Self {
        match self.direction {
           // ...
        };
        self
    }

    pub fn instructions(self, instructions: &str) -> Self {
        for instruction in instructions.chars() {
            match instruction {
                'A' => { self.advance(); },
                'R' => { self.turn_right(); },
                'L' => { self.turn_left(); },
                _   => {
                    println!("{} is not a valid instruction", instruction);
                },
            };
        }
        self
    }
```

I get this error :

```
enter code hereerror[E0382]: use of moved value: `self`
  --> src/lib.rs:60:26
   |
60 |                 'A' => { self.advance(); },
   |                          ^^^^ value moved here in previous iteration of loop
   |
   = note: move occurs because `self` has type `Robot`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `self`
  --> src/lib.rs:61:26
   |
60 |                 'A' => { self.advance(); },
   |                          ---- value moved here
61 |                 'R' => { self.turn_right(); },
   |                          ^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `self` has type `Robot`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I think I get the error because `advance()` returns `self`, but I don't understand why the value is still moved as it's used inside a block. Do I really have to implement `Copy` or am I missing a lifetime use case?

Comment: Could you do it with borrowing? Also, why not implement `Copy`?

Comment: Don't implement `Copy`, but read about [the builder pattern](https://aturon.github.io/ownership/builders.html)

Comment: @EliSadoff I'm actually trying to learn how to write good code. I think copying here would be bad because it would take resources unnecessarily.

Comment: @wimh: the code construction look alike the one I was trying to build, but I didn't find my answer in it. Thank you for the link, this pages seems full of great things by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I think I get the error because advance() returns self ?

No, you're getting that error because `advance` *consumes* `self` (and your other methods do, too).

The idiomatic solution to your problem is almost certainly to have your methods take a mutable reference (`&mut`) to `self` instead of taking `self` by value. E.g. the signature `pub fn turn_right(mut self) -> Self` would become `pub fn turn_right(&mut self)` (note that the latter does not return anything). You can manipulate the robot's state through the reference, and your `instructions` function should work fine.

If for some reason you want to continue to have the methods take `self` by value, you could rewrite `instructions` as follows:

```
pub fn instructions(self, instructions: &str) -> Self {
    let mut robot = self;
    for instruction in instructions.chars() {
        robot = match instruction {
            'A' => { robot.advance() },
            'R' => { robot.turn_right() },
            'L' => { robot.turn_left() },
            _   => {
                println!("{} is not a valid instruction", instruction);
                robot
            },
        };
    }
    robot
}
```

I.e. continue passing the robot's state by value, but make sure that the new state is bound to a variable at every loop iteration.
(I've not tried to compile this code, but the principle should be sound.)

Comment: Thank you, your second solution actually worked. I did try to use references but I had the same problem because the test suite uses chaining calls. If I understand well, the fact that the returned `self` from advance for example, was moving the value, but it was never moved back to the `fn instructions` context ?

Comment: Looking at the other exercism users, you can actually do it with fold : 

        instructions.chars().fold(self, |robot, c| {
            match c {
                'L' => robot.turn_left(),
                'R' => robot.turn_right(),
                'A' => robot.advance(),
                _ => panic!("unexpected char")
            }
        })

Comment: @stamm Yes, that's exactly the problem. Once you pass a value to a method by value, you can no longer use it. But since your methods return the changed state, you can continue using that if you assign the return value to a variable.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the other users answers, you can actually do it with fold :

```
pub fn instructions(self, instructions: &str) -> Self {
    instructions.chars().fold(self, |robot, c| {
        match c {
            'L' => robot.turn_left(),
            'R' => robot.turn_right(),
            'A' => robot.advance(),
            _ => panic!("unexpected char")
        }
    })
}
```

It seems to keep moving back robot into the scope.