# What is the best way to reuse a borrowed struct field if it doesn't implement the Copy or Clone trait?

Tags: rust, ownership

I am writing a client for a TCP server

```
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::io::{Read, Write, Error};

pub struct Client {
    addr: String,
    conn: Option<TcpStream>,
}

impl Client {
    pub fn connect(&mut self) {
        let res = TcpStream::connect(&self.addr);
        match res {
            Ok(c) => {
                self.conn = Some(c);
            },
            Err(_) => panic!(),
        }
    }

    pub fn version(self) -> Result<[u8; 8], Error> {
        let mut ver: [u8; 8] = [0;8];
        let command_string = b"VERSION\r\n";
        let res = self.conn.unwrap().write(&command_string[0..]);
        match res {
            Ok(_) => self.conn.unwrap().read(&mut ver[..]),
            Err(e) => panic!(e)
        };
        Ok(ver)
    }
}
```

The version method returns an error

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `self.conn`
```

when I try to reuse the reference. I thought about using `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` but since these traits are not implemented for TCPStream I am not sure what to do. What would be the best way to achieve reading and writing to a server in a method (btw there will be many such methods like version which will both read and write to the server)

I am still new to rust and trying to wrap my head around ownership concepts so I apologise if this is a stupid question but since I want to discuss various approaches (if indeed there are multiple approaches to solving this problem) to reuse un-Clonable/Copyable fields I thought this question was worth asking.

Comment: I made a few, (to me) fairly conservative assumptions about your code to get it to compile; please review the changes and fix the code if my changes do not reflect your problem.

Comment: thanks for adding the missing imports @trentcl it slipped my mind while drafting the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The version method returns an error when I try to reuse the reference

`self.conn` is not a reference; it is an owned value. Because `Option::unwrap` takes it by value (and its type does not implement `Copy`), you can't reuse it after calling `.unwrap()` on it; that would lead to unsafety.

But you could just store the result of calling `unwrap` into a new variable, and use that instead:

```
    pub fn version(self) -> io::Result<[u8; 8]> {
        let mut ver: [u8; 8] = [0;8];
        const COMMAND_STRING: &[u8] = b"VERSION\r\n";
        let mut conn = self.conn.unwrap();
        conn.write(COMMAND_STRING)?;
        conn.read(&mut ver[..])?;
        Ok(ver)
    }
```

This is possible because `io::Write::write` and `io::Read::read` both take `&mut self`, which means that neither one needs to take `conn` by value. Instead, `conn` will be dropped at the end of `version`. See also [How to prevent a value from being moved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664099/how-to-prevent-a-value-from-being-moved)

I've made several further changes, which you may consider suggestions:

- `io::Result<_>` is an alias for `Result<_, io::Error>`, so I changed the declared return type. This is a common pattern in many libraries, and I find this form easier to understand quickly.
- `conn.read()` returns an `io::Result`, which was previously being ignored. Now `conn.write()` and `conn.read()` both raise errors to the caller with the special `?` operator. You can replace `?` with `.unwrap()` if you want errors to panic instead of propagate. See [What is this question mark operator about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917566/what-is-this-question-mark-operator-about)
- `COMMAND_STRING` is a `const`ant. It's debatable whether having this name at all is useful compared to just `conn.write(b"VERSION\r\n")`, but if you're going to have it, a `const` seems the right way to go. In principle the compiler can optimize `const`s better than regular variables; in practice it's not likely to make much difference in this case, but when a `const` is more explicit about how the value is used, there's no reason not to.

#### Using an actual reference

If you actually want `version` to take `self` by reference, and therefore you *don't* want it to unwrap and destroy `self.conn`, you can use `Option::as_ref` to make that work.

```
    pub fn version(&self) -> io::Result<[u8; 8]> {  // NOTE: `&self`
        let mut ver: [u8; 8] = [0;8];
        let mut conn = self.conn.as_ref().unwrap(); // NOTE: `.as_ref()`
        conn.write(b"VERSION\r\n")?;
        conn.read(&mut ver[..])?;
        Ok(ver)
    }
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b353b0a0aa23c9c1bdf9d13f321cba91)

`as_ref` turns a `&Option<_>` into a `Option<&_>`, so that `unwrap`ping it does not consume `self.conn` but just returns the reference. See [Cannot move out of borrowed content when unwrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338659/cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content-when-unwrapping).